# HTML php form validation and security

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have decided to remove my email address (an image) from my buisiness website and use a HTML form with reCAPTCHA to keep out the bots, so i have been learning some php.
The more i learn the less certain i am about the way forward.
I have two scenarios at the moment:

1 - I use somthing simple like:

```
<?PHP
$email_to_me = "my email address";
$name =$_POST['name'];
$email =$_POST['email'];
$comment =$_POST['comment'];
mail($email_to_me, $name, $comment, "from: .$email");
header("Location: contact.html");
?>
```

which will email me the message, redirect the user back to where they were but will not give the user a message sent confirmation.

2 - I use somthing like:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
$comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
}
function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>
```

Plus some field validation/error messages in the form.

Hopefully this will keep me on my HTML contact page and allow feedback to users of errors filling in fields and a confirmation can be message sent.

Is the second method safe against Cross-site scripting and other hacking methods?
I am getting my info from the www3schools.com.
I just want rid of the spam and virus attacks an email address on a website causes.
Any comments, thoughts, sites with relevent info, alternatives appreciated.

Thanks Uncoded

Comment: thanks for the edit David

Answer (score 0):

PHP do not allow site scriptings. Look for offsite domains in your javascript. Protect your data (which you store in db) with escape string and so on. If you need to solve some problem add your code in a question.